# Calculate probability based on grouping variables in R

Tags: r, probability

I need to calculate the probability of a response(df$C) based on some grouping variables and write the output back into the df.

As an example for my data

```
A B C
1 1 1
2 1 0
3 1 1
1 2 0
2 2 1
3 2 1
```

So ultimately I need the mean probability of the value '1' appearing in df$C, for each value in df$A. df$A values are repeated in the grouping variable df$B.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: yes, sorry, so I need to result for each A, for every group in B

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dplyr`.  In your example, there is only one sample in each grouping of A and B columns, so the resulting column is the same as column C.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% group_by(B, A) %>%
  mutate(res = mean(C==1))
#   A B C res
# 1 1 1 1   1
# 2 2 1 0   0
# 3 3 1 1   1
# 4 1 2 0   0
# 5 2 2 1   1
# 6 3 2 1   1
```

---

Data

```
dat <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), B = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), C = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), res = c(0.5, 0.5, 
1, 0.5, 0.5, 1)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "res"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I am starting to love base R solutions, here is mine:

```
df1 <- split(df, list(df$A, df$B))
pr <- lapply(df1, function(x) mean(x$C == 1) )
df1 <- unsplit(df1, list(df$A, df$B))
df1$pr <- unlist(pr)
df1
A B C pr
1 1 1 1  1
2 2 1 0  0
3 3 1 1  1
4 1 2 0  0
5 2 2 1  1
6 3 2 1  1
```